# setting focus to a textbox during a loop

Tags: c#

I want to make a small kind of calculator.
This  calculator would randomly choose numbers between 1 and 1000, and you would have to answer them.
You would keep a score from the good and wrong answers.
Everything is working as long as I only run it once.

If I set a loop it only allows me to answer the last time. How can I make my program stop after every loop? I've tried to set focus to the textbox where you should give the answer, but it doesn't set the focus until the last loop is finished.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    txtResultaat.Focus();
}
```

Apparently this makes it run 5 times through the loop, but it only allows me one opportunity to type something into the textbox.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: You need to rethink the design of your application. You need to wait for the event raised when the user enters text into the current text box before moving onto the next.

Comment: Can you show more parts of your code? We do not know how your method works. Mb you don't use threads and just your ui freez after loop start.

Answer (score 0):

Well you didn't tell the program to actually stop at all, as you are just having it loop 5 times and set the focus each time to the textbox.  A better way to do this would be to maintain some sort of counter of how many times they have answered so far (a global variable would be easiest for this level of program.  Then just on program load have the program ask for the first numbers, then have that event end.  When the user clicks the answer button, in the button event you then determine if they were right or wrong.  Then at the end of the event, you output the new question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I want to be strictly theoretical, the answer for your question is: use the **break** instruction.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    txtResultaat.Focus();
    break;
}
```

That will achieve what you asked for:

> Can anyone tell me how i can make my program stop after every loop?

If it will make your program run correctly and do what you want to do... that my friend, is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another design ( working with a while loop instead of a for loop) made it work.